# Conditions under which a known vector valued function the gradient of some function

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

Suppose that we have a vector valued function $D(x)$ with derivative $H(x)$ and that both of these are smooth. Under what conditions does there exist a function $f(x)$ such that $\nabla f(x) = D(x)$? Is there a functional form for it? I was looking for the multivariate equivalent of the second fundamental theorem of calculus, but was coming up empty.

In my particular case, $H$ is symmetric and semi-definite.

Comment: Helmholtz's theorem is known as the fundamental theorem of vector calculus. As usual in higher dimensions, the statement and application is not as straightforward as in the one-dimensional case.  Consider for example change-of-variables in integration.

Answer (score 1):

By [Helmholtz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) -- the fundamental theorem of vector calculus --  any **continuously differentiable** vector field that vanishes at infinity sufficiently fast can be decomposed into  irrotational and solenoidal parts of the form

$$\mathbf{D} = \nabla f + \nabla \times \mathbf{a}$$

We can find $f$ and $\mathbf{a}$ given the divergence and curl of the vector field since

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{D} = \nabla \cdot \nabla f + \nabla \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf{a} = \nabla^2f$$

and

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{D} = \nabla \times \nabla f + \nabla \times \nabla  \times \mathbf{a} = \nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf{a},$$

leading to linear partial differential equations that can be solved with suitable boundary conditions.

If $\mathbf{D}$ is curl-free (irrotational), then $\mathbf{D} = \nabla f$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm still a bit fuzzy as to what the conditions are for the existence of $f$. Is it the vector field vanishing fast enough? Obviously, a non-symmetric $H$ would preclude $D$ being a gradient.

Comment: Do you have a specific example? As you say if $H = \nabla f$ then the matrix of $DH$ would have to have a an obvious symmetry.  What you have may just not reduce to a simple solenoidal or irrotational form.  The trace of $DH$ is the divergence so if that is not $0$ then we can’t have $H = \nabla \times a$.

Comment: Sorry, a little confused by your comment. The way I had is set up was $D=\nabla f$ and $H = \nabla^2 f$. H is positive semi-definite. The actual problem is related to generalized method of moments and would require too much background to post here.

Comment: I meant $D$ but wrote $H$ instead in the comment.  I also wanted to use $D$ as the derivative operator, so DD is even more confusing. I can refresh my memory about GMM.  If I come up with anything I’ll get back to you.

Comment: It seems that $D$ is a gradient of a function iff $H$ is symmetric. See (in 2D): http://steiner.math.nthu.edu.tw/disk3/cal01/reconst1.pdf .  Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834607/is-it-possible-to-reverse-a-gradient-vec-nabla-operation

Comment: Also consistent with Helmholtz’s theorem since the curl of the vector field is zero in that case.