# Finding an unknown function using inverse of a gradient vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have a function $F = (x + 2y+4z) \hat i +(2x-3y-z) \hat j + (4x-y+2z) \hat z$, while another one is unknown $\psi$ function. The problem is $F = \nabla \psi $ to find the unknown function $\psi$. I know $\nabla$ is a gradient function and how to calculate it if a known valued function is given. [Is it possible to reverse a gradient ($\vec{\nabla}$) operation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834607/is-it-possible-to-reverse-a-gradient-vec-nabla-operation) provided an example, but it doesn't solve my problem. Any suggestions are highly appreciable.

Comment: This is a standard topic in multivariable calculus. Do you have a book to read to see some examples?  If not you could try  https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcIII/ConservativeVectorField.aspx and https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/4.-triple-integrals-and-surface-integrals-in-3-space/part-c-line-integrals-and-stokes-theorem/session-89-gradient-fields-and-potential-functions

Comment: Thank you @Max for your suggestion and it really solved the problem I was facing.

Comment: Glad to hear that! You could post your solution and accept it. This helps reduce the number of "unanswered" questions. Plus it would help you ensure you solved it correctly.

Comment: Okay @Max I will post my solution shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to find the potential function $\psi(x,y,z)$, of $\vec F = (x + 2y+4z) \hat i +(2x-3y-z) \hat j + (4x-y+2z) \hat z = P \hat i + Q \hat j + R \hat z$. Let's for the time being treat it as $f(x,y,z)$ for generality. Here we have to prove $\vec F = \nabla f$.
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = P,\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = Q, \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = R. \tag{1}\label{1}$$
We also use notation as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = f_x$,... etc.
Now integrating w.r.t z we get:
$$\int f_z dz = \int (4x-y-2z)dz = 4xz-yz+z^2 + g(x,y) \tag{2}\label{2} $$ where g(x,y) is a constant of integration, because if we differentiate w.r.t z the all terms except those containing z variable would vanish. So, from equation \eqref{1}, differentiating w.r.t x and equating to P gives us.
$$\begin{equation}f_x = x + 2y + 4z + g_x(x,y) = x + 2y + 4z = P \\ \implies g_x(x,y) = 0 \quad and \quad \int g_x(x,y) = g(x,y) = h(y) \\
 \implies f(x,y,z) = 4xz-yz+z^2 + h(y)
\end{equation}$$
So, in order to find the constant of integration h(y), we can compute using equation \eqref{1}, and finding only those terms containing y.
$$\implies f_y = 2x - z + h^{'}(y) = 2x - 3y - z = Q \\ 
\implies h^{'}(y) = -3y \implies h(y) = -\frac{3}{2}y^2 + c$$
Hence, the potential function $f(x,y,z)$ would be w.r.t integration of z, so we can write:
$$f(x,y,z)_z = 4xz - yz + z^2 -\frac{3}{2}y^2 + c \tag{3}\label{3}$$

But this is not complete solution. So we have to repeat steps from equation \eqref{2} to \eqref{3}. Take first term (i.e., P) and integrate w.r.t x we have:
**Step 2:** $$  
\int f_x = f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + 2xy + 4xz + g(y,z) \\
\implies \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2x-z-3y + g_y(y,z) =  2x-z-3y = Q \\
\implies g^{'}(y,z) = 0 \implies g(y,z) = h(z) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 4x-y-h^{'}(z) =  4x-y + 2z = R \\
\implies h^{'}(z) = 2z \implies h(z) = z^2 + c
 $$
So we have
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red] {f(x,y,z)_x = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + 2xy + 4xz + z^2 + c}\tag{4}\label{4}$$
**Step 3:** Now again using integration w.r.t y and repeat above steps.
$$\int f_Y = f(x,y,z) = 2xy + \frac{3}{2}y^2 - yz + g(x,z) \\
\implies g^{'}(x,z) = 0 \implies g(x,z) = h(z) \\
\implies h^{'}(z) = 2z \implies h(z) = z^2 .
$$
So we have
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red] {f(x,y,z)_y = \frac{3}{2}y^2 + 2xy - yz + z^2 + c}\tag{5}\label{5}$$
From equations \eqref{3}, \eqref{4}, \eqref{5}, take all common and non-common terms but only write them once. So we obtain final resultant in the form
$$f(x,y,z) = \psi (x,y,z) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + 2xy + 4xz + z^2 -yz - \frac{3}{2}y^2 + c$$
Let's prove our results using $\nabla f$ to obtain $\vec F$.
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{array}\right]f = \left[\begin{array}{c}
x+2y+4z\\
2x-3y-z\\
4x+2z-y\end{array}
\right] = \vec F
$$
Hope this makes sense. If am wrong in any part and as whole calculation please notify me.